# How to paste in successive rows

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub NSV_LINK()
Dim cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In Rng
If cell.Value = "Hemanta" Then cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)
Next cell
End Sub
```

In the code above, I want the macro to copy and paste values in successive rows in sheet 2. However, I have hard coded the destination cell i.e, the value gets pasted at A1. How do I write the cell destination, so that the values get pasted in successive rows? Cells(i, 1)...Something like this. And then i takes a range from, let's say 1 to 20. How do I write this in code?

Comment: There are tons of example on internet for this. Use google before posting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a counter and you have to increment it

```
Sub NSV_LINK()
Dim cell As Range, Rng As Range, r As Long
Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
r = 1
For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Value = "Hemanta" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(2).Cells(r, 1)
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. The code works fine, but there is a problem. There are gaps between the pasted rows in sheet 2. This is because, when the code finds another name in the range(other than Hemanta), it does not copy the row, but the counter gets increased by 1. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

you can adapt the same technique you already used in `Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` to make destination range dynamic:

```
Sub NSV_LINK()
    Dim cell As Range, Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In Rng
        If cell.Value = "Hemanta" Then cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' make destination range dynamic to target sheeet column A first not empty cell after last not empty one
    Next cell
End Sub
```